# Change detection in probabilities

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose I flip a "strange" coin repeatedly and note the sequence of outcomes, H, H, T and so on.

The coin is strange in the sense that prob(H) and prob(T) can change from flip to flip.

Assuming I want to detect the changes as accurately an quickly as possible, what is the best procedure for doing this?

The answer has obvious interest for a gambler who wants to know if he has lost, or gained, an edge in a situation where the objective probabilities are unknown.

My current thinking is frequency-based. I suppose one could look over a particular horizon of flips and determine if the number of H's observed, say, is consistent with the probability one though was generating the stream.

For example, if I believe prob(H) is 0.5, but I then observe 15 T's in a row, then somewhere in this stream, the probability might have changed. And I suppose the point I would guess it has changed is the first point in the stream where 0.5 becomes unlikely (at some level of confidence). That is my thinking. I am not sure it is good.

Comment: With just the sequence of  heads and tails you can't detect that change. You don't have enough information. If this problem comes to you from somewhere you can [edit] the question to give us lots of context and some examples. Then maybe we can help.

Comment: You must assume a prior over the changes in probability.

Comment: Ethan Bolker, the problem is one I am thinking about. I think David G. Stork is right, but it would be interesting to come closer to knowing such a procedure.